# Problem with beamer's \pause in alignments

Tags: beamer, align, pause

I have the following code, (**edit:**) now without `aligned`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> { \setbeamercovered{transparent} }

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[
  \begin{cases}
  %\begin{aligned}
  v(t,x) &= g(t,x), \\
  \pause
  u(x) &= f(x) %& (x\in\mathbb R)
  %\end{aligned}
  \end{cases}
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

(In the first version of the question, nothing was commented out.)

It compiles nicely, but everything except "u(x)" already shows up on the first slide if I use beamer.cls `v 1.70 2007/03/11 18:50:44`. On another computer at work we have an older version installed, namely `v 1.55 2004/10/11 16:09:50`; there everything works as expected: On the first slide, the full second line is shown in transparent style.

The same happens if I use plain TeX's `\halign`, so `cases` is not the culprit. Moreover, if I don't use `\setbeamercovered{transparent}`, then everything works as expected. In other words, `\pause` doesn't work together with `\setbeamercovered{transparent}` and `\halign`.

Is this a bug in `beamer` introduced between versions `1.55` and `1.70`? (If yes, then I'm surprised since it'd regard it quite a serious one.) Does anyone know a workaround that doesn't involve as much markup as Matthew's answer to my original question?

Comment: This is true with v3.10, but I wonder if it might also be an AMS thing. Perhaps do `\listfiles` on both systems and report any other differences in addition to `beamer`. (Also, this might be best as a bug report for `beamer`.)

Comment: @Joseph: Puh, reporting any other differences means a long list, but the only AMS differences are in `amssymb` and `amsfonts`.

Comment: @Joseph: I finally found the "culprit": It's `pdftex.def`. On my old installation I have the version `2002/06/19 v0.03k`, and with this it works as expected! I haven't yet the slightest clue why this is so.

Comment: @Joseph: (I should have listened to you earlier!! By the way, even though `align` does wicked things, `\pause` works _amazingly_ well inside `align` with my old `pdftex.def`. Do you know by any chance where I can find all the other old versions? So that I can look for the last "working" version?)

Comment: I'd use the TeX Live SVN for this: http://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/

Comment: @Joseph: Thanks a lot! I was lucky: they only have the versions starting from `0.03r`, and the last "working" version is `0.03t`. From `0.04` I get the observed buggy behaviour.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(*Posting this as a separate answer since I seriously propose the code here as a bug fix for* `beamer`, *or maybe even better for* `pgfsys-pdftex.def`.)

In the end I found out the real cause of my trouble: `beamerbasecolor.sty` redefines the `\reset@color` command, and the redefinition contains the line

```
\pgfsys@color@unstacked{beamer@tempcolor}%
```

The [`pgf` manual](http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/contrib/tex-contrib/beamer/pgf-1.01/doc/generic/pgf/version-for-tex4ht/en/pgfmanualse33.html) explains:

> `\pgfsys@color@unstacked{<LATEX color>}`
>   This slightly obscure command causes the color stack to be tricked. When called, this command should set the current color to `<LATEX color>` without causing any change in the color stack.

The command `\pgfsys@color@unstacked` is defined in `pgfsys.code.tex` as

```
\def\pgfsys@color@unstacked#1{}
```

so usually it does nothing! However, if the `dvips` driver is used, then `pgfsys-dvips.def` is loaded, which contains the line

```
\def\pgfsys@color@unstacked#1{\special{ps: \XC@usecolor{#1}}}
```

There is no such line in `pgfsys-pdftex.def`, i.e., the command really does nothing if the document is compiled with `pdflatex`. (And this was quite alright with `pdftex.def` up to version `0.03t`.)

Now the interesting thing is: if you compile the code from the question with `latex -> dvips`, then the output is just as one would expect! Thus, the solution is to also give a proper definition of `\pgfsys@color@unstacked` for the case that the `pdftex` driver is used. This definition should then go to `pgfsys-pdftex.def`. Here's a quick fix that defines the command in the preamble if needed:

[image: animated output of 1 frame with 3 overlays]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> { \setbeamercovered{transparent} }
\makeatletter
\def\pdftex@driver{pdftex.def}
\ifx\Gin@driver\pdftex@driver
  \def\pgfsys@color@unstacked#1{%
    \pdfliteral{\csname\string\color@#1\endcsname}%
  }
\fi
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[
  \begin{cases}
  \begin{aligned}
  v(t,x)&= g(t,x), \\ \pause
   u(x) &= f(x) & \pause
           (x\in\mathbb R)
  \end{aligned}
  \end{cases}
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please report to the `pgf` people: `beamer` just uses the code from this 'layer', and I am very reluctant to start patching other peoples stuff unless really necessary.

Comment: @Joseph: I'll do that. (I'll just ping Christian Feuersänger here.)

Comment: @Hendrik: Excellent analysis. I agree that it sounds like a good patch for the driver. But I honestly can't judge about the risk of that change... could you post it on the pgf mailing list? https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/pgf-users

Comment: @Christian: Thanks! The risk should be 0: I did a grep in my root tex directory, and `\pgfsys@color@unstacked` is only ever used in `beamerbasecolor.sty`. About posting this on the pgf mailing list: Could you please do that for me?

Comment: @Christian: Thanks a lot for posting the possible patch.

Comment: @HendrikVogt the patch is now in pgf CVS. Thanks for contributing it.

Comment: @Christian: Terrific, I'm very happy to hear that.

Answer (score 38):

From the beamer manual, in the middle of a use case:

> Euclid finds that he can also add a `\pause` between the definition and the example. So, `\pause`s seem to
>   transcede environments, which Euclid finds quite useful. After some experimentation he finds that *`\pause` only does not work in `align` environments*. He immediately writes an email about this to beamer’s author, but receives a polite answer stating that the implementation of *`align` does wicked things and there is no fix for this*. Also, Euclid is pointed to the last part of the user’s guide, where a workaround is described.  (emphasis added)

Here is my workaround, using `\action`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> { \setbeamercovered{transparent} }

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[
  \begin{cases}
  \begin{aligned}
  \action<+->{v(t,x) &= g(t,x), \\}
  \action<+->{u(x)} &\action<.->{=f(x)} & \action<.->{(x\in\mathbb R)}
  \end{aligned}
  \end{cases}
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

It's surprising that the second line has to have each cell of the align enclosed in an action specification while the first line can go in a single one (maybe that has something to do with the fact that it's shown by default on all slides).  But I remember Till's advice to Euclid:

> `align` does wicked things and there is no fix for this.

**Added**: `\action` is a generic `\only` if I recall correctly.  And the incremental overlay specifications like `<+->` are very much worth learning.  See Section 8 of the beamer manual, or at least it's Section 8 of my 3.06 manual: "Creating Overlays."

Comment: Ah yes: now I remember reading this :-)

Comment: Tsk, tsk: you forgot to indent all your code.  More seriously, I must look up `\action`; I've no idea what that does.

Comment: Thanks for telling me about `\action`. I'll try it tomorrow. However, I do know a fix for the wicked things: _Use the old installation_. Not quite satisfactory, obviously.

Comment: Well, it works, thanks. But for the moment I'll stay with the old installation since it's too many `\action` s to type, and the code won't be as clear any more. Perhaps you know a less wicked replacement for `aligned`?

Comment: [There is a fix for this!](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75550)

Comment: I think you have to specify `<2->`, `<3->` etc instead of `<+->`. For me it did not work otherwise. The beamer user guide states the same.

Answer (score 17):

Finally I followed [Joseph's advice](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6348/problem-with-beamers-pause-in-alignments#comment10077_6348), and in the end found an easy fix for my problem: redefine `\beamerorig@set@color` and `\beamerorig@reset@color` to what they were before 2007. With the code below, the `\pause`s work exactly like expected:

[image: animated output of 1 frame with 3 overlays]

I also tested this with two sets of real-world slides, and encountered no unwanted side effects.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> { \setbeamercovered{transparent} }
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\makeatletter
\def\beamerorig@set@color{%
  \pdfliteral{\current@color}%
  \aftergroup\reset@color
}
\def\beamerorig@reset@color{\pdfliteral{\current@color}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[
  \begin{cases}
  \begin{aligned}
  v(t,x)&= g(t,x), \\ \pause
   u(x) &= f(x) & \pause
           (x\in\mathbb R)
  \end{aligned}
  \end{cases}
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

So it might well be that "`align` does wicked things" (see [Matthew's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6352)), but before 2007, this was not relevant if `\setbeamercovered{transparent}` was used, so for me, `\pause` worked amazingly well within `align`. (A fix for the case that `\setbeamercovered{transparent}` is *not* used can be found in [this answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75550).)

And what happened in 2007? Version 0.04a of `pdftex.def` was released, with support of color stacks. For this, new definitions of `\set@color` and `\reset@color` were used; these are what `\beamerorig@set@color` and `\beamerorig@reset@color` are `\let` to in `beamerbasecolor.sty`. And it appears that this color stack version doesn't work properly in `align` and friends. In the code above, I used the definitions of `\set@color` and `\reset@color` form [version 0.03t of `pdftex.def`](http://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def?revision=1959&view=co).

Comment: Just wanted to say that this worked flawlessly. Thank you very much.

Comment: Worked very well with `\pause` and `\uncover`. However, the answer by Matthew didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

If you don't mind using `eqnarray` in place of `align`, then you can get the pauses to work. 
At least that is my experience.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! Feel free to visit our [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to get the most out of our site.

Comment: Sorry to ask, but did you test your answer? I get the same problem with `eqnarray`. Moreover, note that I don't use `align` at all, only `cases`.

Comment: Switching to `eqnarray*` worked for me.

Comment: @AmritanshuPrasad - Thanks, that helped. Although eqnarray defaults to center rather than left alignment. One can use equation environment along with left aligned. A minimal example is \begin{equation*}
  \left.\begin{aligned} 2 + 3 = 5 \pause
   \end{aligned}
 \right.
  \end{equation*}

Comment: @User3568 Try using eqnarray with an extra ampersand, like: "a&=& b+1\\c&=&d+1". The first column is right-aligned, the second is centred, and the third is left-aligned.

Answer (score 2):

(Resurrecting the question because I had the same issue.) Simply replacing `\pause` inside AMS environments by an incremental overlay specification `\uncover<+(1)->{...}` works nicely:

```
\begin{frame}{Title}
  Stuff.\pause
  \[
    \begin{cases}
    \begin{aligned}
      v(t,x) &= g(t,x), \\
      \uncover<+(1)->{
        u(x) &= f(x) \quad (x\in\mathbb R)
      }
    \end{aligned}
    \end{cases}
  \]
  \pause
  More stuff.
\end{frame}
```