# Equation numbering problems in AMSMath environments with \pause

Tags: beamer, equations, amsmath, pause

I'm writing a beamer presentation, and trying (unsuccessfully) to use `\pause` to step through a **numbered** array of equations, with the equations appearing in turn, and the corresponding numbers appearing at the correct time (i.e. when the equation first appears).

***edit*: I have partially solved the problem, using a variant on the `\alt` trick described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11571/uncover-a-multiline-equation-with-beamer/11617#11617), but with some vertical wiggling.**

The solution ought to be a little more elegant than the one I've proposed below, given that the end user of the document (not me) is likely to need to make changes, and is not an advanced (La)TeX-user.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \begin{gather}
       1\alt<2->{\\2\alt<3>{\\3}{}}{}
    \end{gather}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the `beamer` user guide, in the explanation of `\pause` it says:

> This command does not work inside `amsmath` environments like `align`, since these do really wicked things.

The wicked thing that `align`, `gather` and friends do is that they evaluate the contents of the environment twice. In particular, overlay commands such as `\pause` are executed twice, which can cause mayhem. In the first run, the contents of the environment are just measured; the actual typesetting is done in the second run.

Since the measuring in the first run starts with `\begingroup \measuring@true`, the problem can be fixed quite easily (although according to the `beamer` user guide "there is no fix for this"!): just let `\measuring@true` deactivate the appropriate overlay commands. (Of course one has to find out *what* exactly to deactivate ...) The code below does this, giving the desired output:

[image: animated gif of the output]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\makeatletter
\let\save@measuring@true\measuring@true
\def\measuring@true{%
  \save@measuring@true
  \def\beamer@sortzero##1{\beamer@ifnextcharospec{\beamer@sortzeroread{##1}}{}}%
  \def\beamer@sortzeroread##1<##2>{}%
  \def\beamer@finalnospec{}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{gather}
    1 \\ \pause
    2 \\ \pause
    3
  \end{gather}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Nick: I should point out that I'm not sure about the line `\def\beamer@sortzero##1{\beamer@ifnextcharospec{\beamer@sortzeroread{##1}}{}}` anymore; this has unwanted side effects. Please try it first without that line!

Comment: this is so useful, thank you! could you describe the unwanted side effects of that first line?  I've been using without issues, but wonder in what situations I may need to remove it.

Answer (score 4):

Possibly not the answer you're after, but it can be useful. The idea is to use `\onslide` instead of `\pause`; this, however, will produce still an undesired effect: the last equation number will appear on every slide, as can be seen in the following example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{gather}
    \onslide<1->{1\\}
    \onslide<2->{2\\}
    \onslide<3->{3}
  \end{gather}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

A workaround is to add a new "fictitious" line at the end with no numbering (using `\notag`) and then to adjust the vertical space so that this new fictitious line doesn't add undesired vertical space, as the following example illustrates:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{gather}
    \onslide<1->{1\\}
    \onslide<2->{2\\}
    \onslide<3->{3\\[-\baselineskip]\notag}
  \end{gather}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```