# LaTeX Beamer: \pause doesn't work in \align

Tags: beamer, align

I would like `\pause` to work in `align` environements as it works with normal text.  Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{align*}
    1+1 &= 2 \\  \pause
    1+2 &= 3 \\  \pause
    2+2 &= 4 
\end{align*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

It causes three pages in the PDF, where only the second page has the second equation missing, otherwise all equations are always visible.

I know there are workarounds with `\visible`, but a working `\pause` would be the simplest solution.

Answer (score 5):

The following snippet solves my problem.  Put it somewhere in front of the `\begin{document}`:

```
\makeatletter
\let\save@measuring@true\measuring@true
\def\measuring@true{%
  \save@measuring@true
  \def\beamer@sortzero##1{\beamer@ifnextcharospec{\beamer@sortzeroread{##1}}{}}%
  \def\beamer@sortzeroread##1<##2>{}%
  \def\beamer@finalnospec{}%
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: The code you posted is exactly the same as [@HendrikVogt’s previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/75550/164314) on this site.

Comment: Ah! Thanks for pointing this out. I searched, but didn't find his question.