# Title Page Alignment and Transparenting Paragraph and Lines in Beamer

Tags: beamer, alignment, presentations, transparency

I am not able to set my Title page as I want. Like, there is a huge gap between the title and above space and also to make title big and also to place my name, institute and my university logo in better place. Here is the link of my university logo `https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=i&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cuhimachal.ac.in%2F&psig=AOvVaw1lPuHysHY-TdFCdIFUyBJc&ust=1595416760523000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCJD3j9yc3uoCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD`

```
\documentclass[11pt,t]{beamer} %<----- top align all frame contents
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\setbeamertemplate{frame numbering}[fraction]
\setbeamercolor{progress bar}{fg=green,bg=blue}
\makeatletter
\setlength{\metropolis@progressinheadfoot@linewidth}{3pt}
\makeatother
\metroset{sectionpage=none} %<----- remove all section frames
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel} % <--- number references
\defbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{bullets}{%
    \leavevmode
    \parbox[t]{1em}{\textbullet\hfill}%
    \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-1em\relax}{\inserttocsubsection}\par}
\defbeamertemplate{section in toc}{sections numbered numeric}{%
    \leavevmode%
    \MakeUppercase{\number\inserttocsectionnumber}.\ %
    \inserttocsection\par}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered numeric]
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[bullets]


\begin{document}
        \author{Anshul Sharma}
    \title{Symmetry in Quantum Mechanics}
    \institute {CENTRAL UNIVERSITY OF HIMACHAL PRADESH}
    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node[anchor=north east] at ($(current page.center)+(-2,-2)$){\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth, scale=0.1]{"CUHP LOGO"}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \maketitle
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Also when when doing a presentation we'll want to reveal parts of a frame one after the other. So How to make it possible as i used `setbeamercoveredpage{transparent}` but it seems i am unable to do it.
Below is my code

```
\documentclass[11pt,t]{beamer} %<----- top align all frame contents
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\setbeamertemplate{frame numbering}[fraction]
\setbeamercolor{progress bar}{fg=green,bg=blue}
\makeatletter
\setlength{\metropolis@progressinheadfoot@linewidth}{3pt}
\makeatother
\metroset{sectionpage=none} %<----- remove all section frames
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel} % <--- number references
\defbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{bullets}{%
    \leavevmode
    \parbox[t]{1em}{\textbullet\hfill}%
    \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-1em\relax}{\inserttocsubsection}\par}
\defbeamertemplate{section in toc}{sections numbered numeric}{%
    \leavevmode%
    \MakeUppercase{\number\inserttocsectionnumber}.\ %
    \inserttocsection\par}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered numeric]
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[bullets]


\begin{document}
        \author{Anshul Sharma}
    \title{Symmetry in Quantum Mechanics}
    \institute {CENTRAL UNIVERSITY OF HIMACHAL PRADESH}
    \begin{frame}[plain]
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node[anchor=north east] at ($(current page.center)+(-2,-2)$){\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth, scale=0.1]{"CUHP LOGO"}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \maketitle
    \end{frame}
\begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Overview}
        \tableofcontents
    \end{frame}
    

    
    \section{Symmetries in Classical Physics} % <---- add sections in order to get them listed in the table of contents
    \begin{frame}{\secname} % <----- \secname here used the section's name as a frametitle
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Hi % Here i want that after any para any points or lines the text after it is transparent (not fully but)
            \item Bye
        \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

And also how can we transparent two paragraphs like say

There are many processes in nature where symmetries are violated i.e. say for an example, symmetry often breaks when one goes beyond the level of nucleus i.e. studying physics of particles beyond their fundamental constituents, the Quarks. Some fundamental particles (i.e. $\beta$-particles) violates symmetry known as Parity violation for weak interaction. Also in case of Kaon particles it is seen that CP violation occurs, where to resolve the theory, we use the CPT Theorem.

`Like the below paragraph I want for the reader, text to be transparent (or partially).`

Continuous symmetry and Discrete symmetry. Continuous symmetry are comprised of Translational and Rotational symmetry, where as Discrete symmerty contains Parity, Time Reversal and Charge Conjugation symmetry

Comment: Does `\begin{itemize}[<+->]` instead of `\begin{itemize}`give you the desired result?

Comment: Yeah it worked well but can we make it a little bit transparent and also what about if i want to make transparent two paragraph or two mathematical equation, do i still use `[<+->]` this command.

Comment: I assume you want to show the following items as well but in a light gray text color. To do so, add `\setbeamercovered{transparent}` to the preamble.

Comment: If you want to reveal multiple items at a time, use the `\pause` command as in `\begin{itemize} \item first item on first slide \item second item on first slide \pause \item item on second slide  \end{itemize}`. For more information on that, take a look at Chapter 9 Creating Overlays of the `beamer` manual.

Comment: Regarding: "place my name, institute and my university logo in better place": a better placement here is quite subjective. Could you please prepare a sketch that shows where exactly you would like to place which element on your title frame?

Comment: @leandriis I have rephrased my question would like if you go through again.

Comment: @leandriis Can you knidly run the code till the title page of mine. You would get what i mean to say. Like in title page space is too large between the title and above and also to make title big and `\author` and `\institute` name be in a better position in accordance with the university logo

Comment: `\pause` should wokr here: `\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
There are many processes ... use the CPT Theorem
\pause
   
Continuous symmetry ... Charge Conjugation symmetry
\end{frame}`

Comment: I already took a look at your current titlepage and I understand the issue regarding the white space above the title. But "better position" is subjective. I don't understand where you want to place which element. I definitely think a sketch would make your question a lot clearer.

Comment: Is this the titlepage layout you are looking for? https://i.stack.imgur.com/3s5JC.png

Comment: Yes. Can the name of title be a lil big and the author name and institute name too.The logo is fine

Comment: @leandriis you mean first i should set `\setbeamercovered{transparent}` and the use `\pause` command after any paragraph to work. Will it make fully transparent or partially?

Comment: @leandriis are you framing the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my suggestion on how to change the layout of the titlepage in order to a) remove the large white space above the title, b) increase font sizes of title, author and institute and c) improve the placement of the logo. I have added some comments in the code about the changes I made in comparison to the original definition of the `title page` template from the metropolis theme.

I also included two short examples on how to use the `\pause` command. In combination with `\setbeamercovered{transparent}` which I added to the preamble, upcoming contents are shown in a light gray color:

```
\documentclass[11pt,t]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\setbeamertemplate{frame numbering}[fraction]
\setbeamercolor{progress bar}{fg=green,bg=blue}
\makeatletter
\setlength{\metropolis@progressinheadfoot@linewidth}{3pt}
\makeatother
\metroset{sectionpage=none}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel}
\defbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}{bullets}{%
    \leavevmode
    \parbox[t]{1em}{\textbullet\hfill}%
    \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\textwidth-1em\relax}{\inserttocsubsection}\par}
\defbeamertemplate{section in toc}{sections numbered numeric}{%
    \leavevmode%
    \MakeUppercase{\number\inserttocsectionnumber}.\ %
    \inserttocsection\par}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered numeric]
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[bullets]
\setbeamercovered{transparent} % <----- added


\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{title page}{
  \begin{minipage}[t][\paperheight]{\textwidth} % <---- changed from [b] to [t] alignment
%    \ifx\inserttitlegraphic\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{title graphic}\fi % <--- commented out and moved to the end
%    \vfill% % <---- commented out as not needed with top alignment
    \ifx\inserttitle\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{title}\fi
    \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{subtitle}\fi
    \usebeamertemplate*{title separator}
    \ifx\beamer@shortauthor\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{author}\fi
    \ifx\insertdate\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{date}\fi
    \ifx\insertinstitute\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{institute}\fi
    \ifx\inserttitlegraphic\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{title graphic}\fi % <---- added the titlegraphic here
%    \vfill % <---- commented out as not needed with top alignment
    \vspace*{1mm}
  \end{minipage}
}
\makeatother

\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\LARGE}
\setbeamerfont{author}{size=\large}
\setbeamerfont{institute}{size=\large}


\author{Anshul Sharma}
\title{Symmetry in Quantum Mechanics}
\institute {CENTRAL UNIVERSITY OF HIMACHAL PRADESH}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image}}
\begin{document}



\begin{frame}
    \maketitle
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Overview}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}
    

\section{Symmetries in Classical Physics} 
\begin{frame}{\secname}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item first item on first slide
        \item second item on first slide
        \pause
        \item item on second slide
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
   
\begin{frame}{Frame Title}
    There are many processes ... use the CPT Theorem
    \pause
   
    Continuous symmetry ... Charge Conjugation symmetry
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Here is a way to decrease teh space between title and green line without changing the absolute placement of the line and the elements below it:

```
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{title page}{
  \begin{minipage}[t][\paperheight]{\textwidth} % <---- changed from [b] to [t] alignment
%    \ifx\inserttitlegraphic\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{title graphic}\fi % <--- commented out and moved to the end
%    \vfill% % <---- commented out as not needed with top alignment
\vspace{0.45cm} % <--- move the title down by 0.45cm
    \ifx\inserttitle\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{title}\fi
    \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{subtitle}\fi
    \vspace{-0.45cm} % <---- remove 0.45 cm of white space between title and green line
    \usebeamertemplate*{title separator}
    \ifx\beamer@shortauthor\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{author}\fi
    \ifx\insertdate\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{date}\fi
    \ifx\insertinstitute\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{institute}\fi
%    \bigskip
    \ifx\inserttitlegraphic\@empty\else\usebeamertemplate*{title graphic}\fi % <---- added the titlegraphic here
%    \vfill % <---- commented out as not needed with top alignment
    \vspace*{1mm}
  \end{minipage}
}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Comment: In the code for title image, the positon of title page has shifted upwards. Is it due to `\Large` command or manually you have don as it has moved a little upwards

Comment: The position of the logo changes in comparison to your original code since I used an entirely different method to insert it into the titlepage. Would you like to move it down again?

Comment: I am Sorry for the comment. I meant the title of the slide sorry for wrong information. The title has shifted a little up.

Comment: But istn't that exactly what you asked for in your question. I am a little bit confused now. "shifted up" in comparison to what? In comparison to your original code or in comparison to the image in posted in a previous comment? (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/554437/title-page-alignment-and-transparenting-paragraph-and-lines-in-beamer/554466?noredirect=1#comment1399556_554437)?

Comment: I am saying The title "Symmetry in Quantum Mechanics" is lifted a little up.....

Comment: Lifted up in comparison to what?

Comment: on the page i say.

Comment: As far as I understood, that was exactly what you wanted or am I mistaken? As far as I understood your original question, you wanted to reduce the space above the title, which basically means moving it upwards within the frame? Did I already misunderstood this?

Comment: You are absolutely right Sir, what i mean is can we manually set it as it looks a little bit more than above. Like if it can a little smaller of say 0.1 to 0.15cm

Comment: Is this wat you want to achieve?  https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVp8j.png Every element stays where it ist, just the title is placed a bit lower and closer to the green line.

Comment: I know i am troubling you can it go like 0.5mm up more

Comment: I have updated my answer. Hopefully the new version suits your needs.

Comment: Does the pause command work for `\begin{itemize}` and then `\item .... \pausa` will work? Also will math mathematical equation like `\begin{align}.....\pause \\ .....\pause` too?

Comment: Yes finally it worked as Desired.. thnq

Comment: @AnshulSharma: Regarding the use of `\pause inside of `itemize`: Such an example is already included in my answer. Regarding the use of `\pause` inside og `align`, take a look at the answers to: [Equation numbering problems in AMSMath environments with \pause](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16186/134144)

Comment: Sir i have my presentation and having many problem like as i have many section my content area i.e table of content is not showing up fully. Here is the link of the question i have raised https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/554576/table-of-content-for-too-many-sections

Comment: Sir how can i add department name and my supervisor name and my roll number in the title page

Comment: Where exactly so you want to add the name of your supervisor, the department name and the enrolment number (I assume this is what "roll number" means)? Below your name, above the title, to the right side of the logo, in the same line as the date,.....? There are countless options. Please clarify by providing a sketch of the desired output.

Comment: Sir please please please please i beg of you please help me out. I have lost everyhting my effort in making the presentation. it is giving me document class error. please sir please help me out please help me..tommorror is the dead line please sir. here is the link https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/554611/two-documentclass-or-documentstyle-commands-documentclass-error

Comment: Please help me i am lost. I am lost and not feeling nice. please help me put sir please here is the link. Thank god you replied and online please help me out sir here is the link https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/554611/two-documentclass-or-documentstyle-commands-documentclass-error