# How can I change the text color in such a way that the effect transcends groups?

Tags: pdftex, color, grouping

I'd like to have a command `\globalred` that makes all subsequent text red, even if the command is issued inside a group. For example, the output of the TeX file

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
a {\globalred b} c
\end{document}
```

should be  [image: desired output], with a red `c`. I do have some very hacky solution, but it only works by redefining the `\set@color` and `\reset@color` commands from `pdftex.def` to what they where up to [version 0.03t](http://www.tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def?revision=1959&view=co) (or by using an old TeX installation before 2007):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{xcolor}
\makeatletter
\def\set@color  {\pdfliteral{\current@color}%
                 \aftergroup\reset@color}
\def\reset@color{\pdfliteral{\current@color}}
\def\globalred  {\xdef\current@color{\xcolor@ {}{1 0 0 rg 1 0 0 RG}{rgb}{1,0,0}}%
                 \set@color}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
a {\globalred b} c
\end{document}
```

This leads me to the following questions:

- Is there an "official" way to achieve what I want?
- Why doesn't `\set@color` from more recent `pdftex.def` versions act globally anymore, although I globally redefine `\current@color` with `\xdef`? (Is this a design choice or just an unforeseen side effect of the new implementation of `\set@color`?)

Let me shortly explain how I came up with this: in my hacky code above, I'm roughly emulating what `beamer` does to produce transparent text. `beamer` aims to do this in a way that transcedes groups (see the [user guide](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf), pages 24 and 79), but it appears that it doesn't work anymore; at least for me, the example on page 79 gives strange output:

[image: strange output of itemize with pauses]

The same problem (and hacky solution) came up in [this question my mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6348/problem-with-beamers-pause-in-alignments).

Comment: @egreg: Oops - thank you! (I think you found a typo in the [`beamer` user guide](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf), page 24 `:-)`)

Comment: @HendrikVogt It's "transcend", actually. `:)`. It's from Latin "trans" plus "scandere" (to climb), not "trans" plus "cedere" (to move). Compare "descend" and "procede".

Comment: @egreg: Thanks, yeah, now I got it. I just copied the word from the `beamer` user guide without thinking about it `:-)`

Answer (score 14):

There is no official way to do it in LaTeX. Color changes are bound to groups. That the "global trick" works with older versions of `pdftex.def` is due to the shortcomings of the color implmentation there. Older versions of pdfTeX do not provide a color stack and have therefore serious trouble with page breaks.

Dvips provides a color stack where the current color is put on the stack in the driver, the color is changed and after the group the color of the stack is restored, `\current@color` is not used during restoring the color value. The same now happens with `pdftex.def` and pdfTeX, if they are not too old. Also pdfTeX improves the color stack of dvips by supporting multiple color stacks. For example, an additional color stack can be used for footnotes (package `pdfcol`) to support color changes in footnotes that are broken across pages. See packages `pdfcolparrallel` or `pdfcolparcolumns` for other examples. Furthermore other parameters than color can be managed this way, see example package `pdftransparent` for transparency or `pdfrender`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{xcolor}
\makeatletter
\def\set@color{%
  \pdfliteral{\current@color}%
  \aftergroup\reset@color
}
\def\reset@color{%
  \pdfliteral{\current@color}%
}
% colorfix stuff for old implementation of color for pdfTeX
\RequirePackage{ltxcmds}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \ltx@ifundefined{@ldc@l@r}{%
    \let\@ldc@l@r\color
    \def\color{%
      \ltx@IfUndefined{if@inlabel}{}{%
        \csname if@inlabel\expandafter\endcsname
        \expandafter\leavevmode\csname fi\endcsname
      }%
      \@ldc@l@r
    }%
  }{}%
  \ltx@ifundefined{@lduseb@x}{%
    \ltx@IfUndefined{usebox}{}{%
      \let\@lduseb@x\usebox
      \def\usebox#1{\@lduseb@x{#1}\reset@color}%
    }%
  }{}%
}

\newcommand*{\globalcolor}{%
  \let\saved@set@color\set@color
  \def\set@color{%
    \saved@set@color
    \global\let\current@color\current@color
    \let\set@color\saved@set@color
  }%
  \color
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
a \textcolor{blue}{b \globalcolor{red}c }d
\end{document}
```

> [image: Example]

`\pdfcolorstack` could be disabled, then `pdftex.def` would automatically switch to the old behaviour. However this would also break other stuff not related to color (e.g. `pdfrender`, `pdftransparent`, …).

And this `\globalcolor` will not work for other drivers like `dvips`.
Therefore I do not recommend this method.

Comment: Tanks a lot for your answer; I think I'll need some time to digest it. It's a shame that there's no official way! I hope this doesn't mean that there's no good way to fix the `beamer` problem I mention at the end of my question.

Comment: If I could upvote more often I would do it.

Comment: May I ask you to have a look at what I did in my answer? Maybe that version doesn't break all the stuff you mention in your answer? (I do see that using `\current@color` in my redefinition of `\reset@color` contravenes the general idea of how `\reset@color` should work.) Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

OK, I came up with another solution that doesn't work by *disabling* the pdf color stack but by *manipulating* it. The idea is to use the `set` option of the `\pdfcolorstack` primitive. I hope this has less side effects than the crude idea from the question. (One downside is that my redefinition of `\reset@color` causes problems at page breaks; see Heiko Oberdieck's comment.)

**Edit:** Now the solution works with `pdflatex` and with `latex -> dvips`. I'm not too happy with the code for the `dvips` driver, but it appears that the driver doesn't complain if `color pop` is used for an empty color stack.

[image: output with c, d and f in red]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\makeatletter
\let\rs@c\reset@color
\def\dvips@driver{dvips.def}
\def\pdftex@driver{pdftex.def}
\ifx\Gin@driver\pdftex@driver
  \def\reset@color{%
    \rs@c
    \pdfcolorstack\@pdfcolorstack set{\current@color}%
  }
\fi
\ifx\Gin@driver\dvips@driver
  \def\reset@color{%
    \rs@c
    \rs@c
    \set@color
  }
\fi
\newcommand*{\globalcolor}{%
  \let\saved@set@color\set@color
  \def\set@color{%
    \saved@set@color
    \let\set@color\saved@set@color
    \global\let\current@color\current@color
  }%
  \color
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\textcolor{green}{%
  a \textcolor{blue}{b \globalcolor{red} c }d \textcolor{black} e
}f
\end{document}
```

Comment: You get the old problems with colors at page breaks of the old implementation without color stacks. Try `\textcolor{blue}{blue\newpage ?color?\color{red}red\newpage}`. Then `?color?` is not blue but red.

Comment: Ah, OK, thank you - that's what I almost expected. But it's no problem for me since I want to use this as a fix for my `beamer` problem, where there are no automatic page breaks. (I added a word of caution to my answer.)