# Color set in \g_galley_par_end_hook_tl does not affect next \item

Tags: color, enumerate, itemize, expl3, l3galley

I'm using the LaTeX3 technique [shown by cfr here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/326947/12440) to prepend a `\color` command to some paragraphs. In the `par_end_hook` I added `\color{black}` to reset the color after the paragraph is done. It all works fine for normal text, but when used in a list, it colors the list index of the *next* item as well, although the text "EndOfParHook" before it appears black (as it should).

Why is that?

PS: I'm not looking to color the list indices as well. For me it would be fine if the 2., the 3. and the 6. were simply black.

[image: This is the result]

And this is the code to produce the image shown above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,l3galley,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_gput_right:Nn \g_galley_par_begin_hook_tl
{
  \color{\NextPartColor}
  \gdef\NextPartColor{black}
}
\tl_gput_left:Nn \g_galley_par_end_hook_tl
{
  \color{black}EndOfParHook
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\NextPartColor{black}
\def\todoPar{\gdef\NextPartColor{red!70!black}}
\def\donePar{\gdef\NextPartColor{green!70!black}}

\begin{document}

\todoPar This works fine for normal paragraphs.

Everything black here, as it should.

\begin{enumerate}
    \item\todoPar Some todo item
    \item\donePar This one is green, but why is the 2 red?
    \item Nothing to do here, but the 3 is green!
    \item Another black one
    \todoPar\item Doesn't matter if we place it before or after the \verb|\item|.
    \item Last one
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem is that the contents of `\g_galley_par_end_hook_tl` are placed in a group. This can easily be checked by adding `\the\currentgrouplevel` into `\g_galley_par_end_hook_tl` and in a normal paragraph (or item). Sadly, making color changes global (as in breaking out of a group) is really messy and driver-dependent in LaTeX. See [How can I change the text color in such a way that the effect transcends groups?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/72747/12440) for the gory details.

---

However, I managed to solve the problem by modifying the `\item` macro to explicitly set the color to `\NextParColor`. That way, we don't even need `\g_galley_par_end_hook_tl`, because the color for the next paragraph is already reset to black at the beginning of the current paragraph.

As a bonus, this also allows us to color the list number itself:

[image: Looks better now]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,l3galley,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_gput_right:Nn \g_galley_par_begin_hook_tl
{
  \color{\NextPartColor}
  \gdef\NextPartColor{black}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\NextPartColor{black}
\def\todoPar{\gdef\NextPartColor{red!70!black}}
\def\donePar{\gdef\NextPartColor{green!70!black}}

%% Hack: Fix wrong-color item labels
\let\OldItem=\item
\def\item{\color{\NextPartColor}\OldItem}

\begin{document}

\todoPar This works fine for normal paragraphs.

Everything black here, as it should.

\begin{enumerate}
    \item\todoPar Some todo item
    \item\donePar This one is green, but why is the 2 red?
    \item This whole line is black. Yay.
    \todoPar\item Before \verb|\item|, it also colors the number.
    \item Last one, also black.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```