# beamer \pause behaves differently inside tabular using different \setbeamercovered option

Tags: tables, beamer

The following MWE demonstrates the problem:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\setbeamercovered{transparent=0}
%\setbeamercovered{invisible}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
a & b \\\pause
c & d
\end{tabular}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

`\pause` effects one row if `\setbeamercovered{invisible}` is used, but only one cell if `\setbeamercovered{transparent=??}` is used.

Is it a bug? Shouldn't it be the same?! Can I write my code to affect the entire row with both of the above?

Comment: I don't know the details, but using `\pause` within a `tabular` environment is probably not a very good idea. Why not simply use `\visible<2>{<second row>}`?

Comment: @Jubobs "using `\pause` within a `tabular` environment is probably not a very good idea" - can you link me things you're referring to by that? Is there other environments where I shouldn't use `\pause`? (these would do as an answer for me)

Comment: How about the explanation given here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6352/18228. I guess in general one should avoid using `\pause` in environments involving arrays

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please disregard [my earlier comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145462/beamer-pause-behaves-differently-inside-tabular-using-different-setbeamercover/145911#comment329468_145462). `\pause` can be used within a `tabular` environment.

To uncover a table rowwise, you should use `\pause`, not after, but *before* a `\\`. The code is adapted from the `beamer` documentation itself (see subsection *23.5 Uncovering a Table Rowwise*).

I don't have a satisfactory explanation for the behaviour your code displays.
As pointed out in [KevinC's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145462/beamer-pause-behaves-differently-inside-tabular-using-different-setbeamercover#comment330578_145462), `\pause` seems to produce surprising results when used inside array-type environment.
The `beamer` doc (subsection 9.1) warns about that:

> This command does not work inside `amsmath` environments like `align`, since these do really wicked things.

Perhaps it is best not to use `\pause` in ways other than those shown in the `beamer` manual.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercovered{invisible}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tabular}{lcccc}
    Class & A & B & C & D           \\
    \hline
    X       & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \pause  \\
    Y       & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \pause  \\
    Z       & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) Altough with the `\setbeamercovered{invisible}` setting `\pause` was the same if I used it after `\\`. It is still (or more) broken if I use `\setbeamercovered{transparent}`.